# Archlinux boots with German ISO keyboard layout even though US ANSI is defined

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, disk-encryption, virtual-consoles

I recently switched from DE-ISO to US-ANSI layout and have an issue across my Archlinux machines that I cannot resolve which is a bit painful as the encryption key expects German layout but my keyboard is US.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Checked that the US keymap is available on my system:

   ```
   ~
   ❯ localectl list-keymaps | grep -iI "us"

   amiga-us
   atari-us
   br-latin1-us
   cz-us-qwertz
   is-latin1-us
   mac-us
   sunt5-cz-us
   sunt5-us-cz
   us
   us-acentos
   us1
   ```
2. Changed `KEYMAP` for the vconsole:

   ```
   ~
   ❯ cat /etc/vconsole.conf
   KEYMAP=us
   FONT=lat9w-16
   ```
3. Ensured that the keymap hook comes before the encrypt one in mkinitcpio:

   ```
   ~
   ❯ grep -iI "hooks" /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
   # The following modules are loaded before any boot hooks are
   # HOOKS
   # This is the most important setting in this file.  The HOOKS control the
   # order in which HOOKS are added.  Run 'mkinitcpio -H <hook name>' for
   #    HOOKS=(base)
   #    HOOKS=(base udev autodetect block filesystems)
   #    HOOKS=(base udev block filesystems)
   #    HOOKS=(base udev block mdadm encrypt filesystems)
   #    HOOKS=(base udev block lvm2 filesystems)
   #    usr, fsck and shutdown hooks.
   HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block keyboard keymap consolefont encrypt filesystems fsck shutdown)
   ```
4. Rebuilt mkinitcpio for the current Linux kernel:

   ```
   ~
   ❯ sudo mkinitcpio -p linux
   ==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset: 'default'
     -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-linux -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-linux.img
   ==> Starting build: 6.0.8-arch1-1
     -> Running build hook: [base]
     -> Running build hook: [udev]
     -> Running build hook: [autodetect]
     -> Running build hook: [modconf]
     -> Running build hook: [block]
   ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: xhci_pci
     -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
     -> Running build hook: [keymap]
     -> Running build hook: [consolefont]
     -> Running build hook: [encrypt]
   ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: qat_4xxx
     -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
     -> Running build hook: [fsck]
     -> Running build hook: [shutdown]
   ==> Generating module dependencies
   ==> Creating zstd-compressed initcpio image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
   ==> Image generation successful
   ==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset: 'fallback'
     -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-linux -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img -S autodetect
   ==> Starting build: 6.0.8-arch1-1
     -> Running build hook: [base]
     -> Running build hook: [udev]
     -> Running build hook: [modconf]
     -> Running build hook: [block]
   ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: qed
   ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: qla1280
   ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: wd719x
   ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: qla2xxx
   ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: bfa
   ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: aic94xx
   ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: xhci_pci
     -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
     -> Running build hook: [keymap]
     -> Running build hook: [consolefont]
     -> Running build hook: [encrypt]
   ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: qat_4xxx
     -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
     -> Running build hook: [fsck]
     -> Running build hook: [shutdown]
   ==> Generating module dependencies
   ==> Creating zstd-compressed initcpio image: /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
   ==> Image generation successful
   ```

However, when I boot the system, it fails to decrypt my device and between two encryption attempts I keep hitting random keys to see which keymap is active and it turns out it's still the German ISO layout.

```
~
❯ uname -a
Linux bunda 6.0.8-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu, 10 Nov 2022 21:14:24 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is there any other location I could have defined that? What else could I check?